# Target window does not appear to receive WM_FONTCHANGE from SendMessage

Tags: c#, powershell, pinvoke, visual-studio-code

I've been working on this off-and-on for several days to get to this point, but now I feel at the end.  **I am trying to get vscode to see my font that I don't have privileges to install.**

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Font
{
    public const UInt32 WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D;
    public static IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xFFFF);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint="AddFontResourceW", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int AddFontResource(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string filePath);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="SendMessageW", SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
}
'@

# skip the invisible windows
$code = (Get-Process -Name code).Where{$_.MainWindowHandle}.MainWindowHandle
Get-ChildItem -Path '/myfonts/*.ttf' | ForEach-Object {
    if ([Font]::AddFontResource($_.FullName)) {
        $null = [Font]::SendMessage($code, [Font]::WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0)
        [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetLastWin32Error()
        ).Message
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning -Message "$($_.BaseName) failed to import."
    }
}
```

Previously, I tried broadcasting, but I don't have admin privileges and I think this was trying to broadcast to shared-resource windows (virtual environment), so the window would just hang.  This led me down the road of trying to target just vscode and see if that would work.

Comment: WM_FONTCHANGE is not documented to work with anything other than HWND_BROADCAST. So I would focus on that. What window just hangs? Have you tried to use PostMessage instead?

Comment: @SimonMourier The `powershell` window hangs that is running the command.  I have not tried `PostMessage` although I saw recommendations for it.  Is it still possible to get return values from the function?  It fires async based on my reading.

Comment: With vscode open, I don't reproduce any issue with SendMessage([Font]::HWND_BROADCAST, [Font]::WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0), admin or not.

Comment: @SimonMourier Are you using a font you don't have installed and does the font within VSCode actually change after the message is processed?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No but that's normal. WM_FONTCHANGE just notifies applications that the font pool has changed, it doesn't change any font automatically.

Comment: @SimonMourier What I mean is: does your font actually render in vscode?  Maybe there is a difference because it's a virtual desktop, but no method I use makes the font available (although I CAN see and use it in other applications like wordpad!).

Comment: yes everything works as expected.